# Off-the-shelf javascript to simultaneously show/hide multiple elements

Tags: javascript, toggle, show

I have text on an html page.

I want to tag parts of speech such as adjectives (e.g. span class="adj"), and use vanilla JS to toggle the visibility of each part of speech using buttons, with hidden or display: none as the initial state.

There would be multiple occurrences of each part of speech on a page and all instances of a particular part of speech (e.g. "adj") should appear simultaneously at the press of a button. They would be shown inline.

I am trying to find some simple off-the-shelf Javascript to achieve what I want. I know no Javascript but I can do simple things like filling in categories (e.g. specifying the class as "noun1" or "noun2"). Preferably I do not want to specify each occurrence as a separate event.

This seems like a commonsense kind of goal but not a single resource seems to address it. W3schools is laughable (tied to id, so only one element at a time). Some resources give faulty solutions containing the old 'double-click' issue (initially you have to click twice). Many are tied to very specific cases, or require knowledge of JS and arrays. I have found nothing that would achieve what I want, that is, one click and all the (tagged) adjectives, nouns, etc. in a stretch of text appear. Am I asking the impossible?

Comment: I'm amazed to get responses so quickly! Thank you for your patience and generosity in answering such an elementary question.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty straight forward. I think I understand your need. A single button for each part of speech that shows the words in text of that part of speech.

The key, as you pointed out, is to put the content in spans. Then, using `data-`
attributes we can uniquely identify each part. Finally, toggle a class that hides or shows the content.

Please note I used the CSS property `visibility` rather than `display`. The reason is because `visibility` retains the space taken even if the content is not *visible*. That seemed to match your use case better than removing as `display` does.

EDIT: [Here is the solution in a plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/TRgpseChLMcFwKK5)

```js
document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', highlight);

function highlight(e) {
  document.querySelectorAll(`[data-part=${e.target.dataset.activate}]`).forEach(el => el.classList.toggle('hidden'));
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button data-activate="adj">Adjectives</button>
  <button data-activate="noun">Nouns</button>
  <button data-activate="verb">Verbs</button>
</div>

<p>The <span data-part="noun" class="hidden">dog</span> <span data-part="verb" class="hidden">jumped</span> over the <span data-part="adj" class="hidden">bright</span> <span data-part="noun" class="hidden">moon</span>.</p>
<p>The <span data-part="adj" class="hidden">beautiful</span> <span data-part="noun" class="hidden">rose</span> <span data-part="verb" class="hidden">wept</span>.</p>
```

Comment: I've tried this and it works. (I changed the styling of hidden to display: none as I want to literally inserts into the text, but it still works. It didn't work when I put the JS into a separate document (xxxx.js) and I'm not sure why...

Comment: I've put this into an external editor program for you (called Plunkr) so that you can see the file structures and tags you need to get external JavaScript and CSS. Please don't forget to accept my answer if it meets you needs. http://next.plnkr.co/edit/TRgpseChLMcFwKK5

Answer (score 1):

Something like that ?

```js
const Bt_toM = document.querySelector('#bt-to-M')
,     Bt_toV = document.querySelector('#bt-to-V')
,     Bt_toS = document.querySelector('#bt-to-S')
,     ElmsTo = document.querySelectorAll('span.word-to')
;
/*
Bt_toM.onclick =_=>{
  ElmsTo.forEach(e=>{
    e.classList.remove('noVisu')
    e.classList.remove('Show_hide')
    e.classList.toggle('magnify')
  })
}
*/
Bt_toV.onclick =_=>{
  ElmsTo.forEach(e=>{
//    e.classList.remove('magnify')
//    e.classList.remove('Show_hide')
    e.classList.toggle('noVisu')
  })
}
/*
Bt_toS.onclick =_=>{
  ElmsTo.forEach(e=>{
    e.classList.remove('noVisu')
    e.classList.remove('magnify')
    e.classList.toggle('Show_hide')
  })
}
*/
```

```css
.magnify   { color: red; background-color: aqua}
.noVisu    { visibility: hidden }
.Show_hide { display: none }
```

```html
<p>I am trying <span class="word-to noVisu">to</span> find some simple off-the-shelf Javascript <span class="word-to noVisu">to</span> achieve what I want.
I know no Javascript but I can do simple things like filling in categories (e.g. specifying the class as "noun1" or "noun2"). 
Preferably I do not want <span class="word-to noVisu">to</span> specify each occurrence as a separate event.</p>

<p>This seems like a commonsense kind of goal but not a single resource seems <span class="word-to noVisu">to</span> address it. 
W3schools is laughable (tied <span class="word-to noVisu">to</span> id, so only one element at a time). 
Some resources give faulty solutions containing the old 'double-click' issue (initially you have <span class="word-to noVisu">to</span> 
click twice). Many are tied <span class="word-to noVisu">to</span> very specific cases, or require knowledge of JS and arrays. I have found 
nothing that would achieve what I want, that is, one click and all the (tagged) adjectives, nouns, etc. 
in a stretch of text appear. Am I asking the impossible?</p>
<hr>
<!--<button id="bt-to-M">magnify "to" on/off </button> -->
<button id="bt-to-V">Visualize "to" on/off </button>
<!--<button id="bt-to-S">Show/hide "to" </button>  -->
```

Comment: I'm using css to get this effect (adding colour etc.) and it works ok. I'm forced to use JavaScript because css apparently can't make elements appear and disappear.

Comment: Apparently you have a big deal on the html / css / JS.
Your question is not clear, and there are 3 ways to understand what you are looking for, I changed my example to show you all 3. If you are looking for another effect than one of these 3 , please specify it more precisely.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was unclear. The request was for "vanilla JS to toggle the visibility of each part of speech using buttons, with hidden or display: none as the initial state."

Your third one, "Show/hide "to"" is what I was looking for, although the initial state should be hidden, not visible.

Comment: So, you just have to change `<span class="word-to">` to `<span class="word-to noVisu">` as I have done on my answer

Comment: Your solution works fine here but I can't reproduce it on my computer. I've added your script to the end of the document, before the body closing tag, and enclosed it inside script tags.

Comment: well, you will find a error message in the console part of your browser (use F12)

Answer (score 0):

I see you are new here,

this javascript function returns all elements with the class name as an array

```
var elements = Document.getElementsByClassName("class");
```

assuming all the adjectives you want to highlight all have the same classes, you can use a for loop to loop through all elements and set the style

```
function buttonClick() {
    var elements = Document.getElementsByClassName("class");
    for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
        elements[i].style.opacity = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that this would work fine but I'm not sure how to set up the buttons to make it work.

Comment: Please note that my comment above is an admission of my own inadequacy, not a criticism of your answer.

Comment: use button onclick to reference a javascript function such as `<button onclick="buttonClick">Sample Button</button>`